# Скрытие блоков jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Доброго времени суток,

У меня есть функция для открытия скрытого div внутри div, но функция будет работать и открывать скрытый блок только если она находится внутри самого этого div блока, выглядит она следующим образом, но мне надо чтобы функция могла открывать этот блок и другой блок с другим классом! Помогите пожалуйста, может другую функцию добавить?

```js
$(".open").click(
  function() {
    openBlock($(this));
  });


function openBlock(el) {
  var el = el,
    input = el.find("input[type=checkbox]").eq(0);
  if (input.prop("checked")) {
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").css("display", "block");
  } else {
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").css("display", "none");
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").children().children(".question").children(".clear-input").val("0");
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").children("0.question").children(".clear-input").val("0");
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").children(".question").children(".test-checkbox").children("input").removeAttr("checked");
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").children(".question").children(".test-checkbox").children("input").removeProp("checked");
    el.parent().parent().children(".open-this").children(".question").children(".test-checkbox").css("background-position", "0 0");
    changeCheckStart($(this));
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <span class="test-checktext" style="font-weight: bold">Тут текст</span>
  <div class="helper"></div>
  <span class="test-checkbox open">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label for="payt3"></label>
    </span>
</div>
<div class="open-this" style="display: none;">
  <div class="question">
    //ТУТ КАКОЕ НИБУДЬ СОДЕРЖИМОЕ
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно. кто такие `этот блок и другой блок с другим классом!` ?

Comment: ну вот в примере есть блок div в нем находится код с чек боксом и с скрытым блоком, по нажатию на чек бокс появляется скрытый блок

Comment: там их четыре.... и что дальше? есть они (он) и...?

Comment: если нажимаю на чекбокс и он checked , то появится блок с классом open-this , если только он находится  в родительском блоке div

Comment: а надо чтобы если чекбокс = checked , то он будет открывать этот блок и еще другой блок  c другим названием класса вне родительского блока

Comment: таки и в чем проблема добавить еще одну строчку с открытием указанного дива с другим названием?

Comment: а как это реализовать , вне родительского блока

Comment: parent().parent().children это отвечает за блок родительский?

Comment: `а как это реализовать , вне родительского блока` -  как ты думаешь, когда ты пишешь конструкцию вида `$(".open").click(` на какой именно элемент это влияет?

Comment: Да просто код не мой, не могу разобраться

Comment: Так может стоит для начала [почитать и поучить основы](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Заглавная_страница) ?